# What is the relation between formal group and formal scheme

Tags: abstract-algebra, schemes, formal-power-series

What is the relation between formal group and formal scheme?

Formal group is power series, which behaves like ' a group law without any group elements'.

Is former one is special case of latter one?

Comment: It depends on context, but usually formal groups are the structure of a formal group scheme on $\widehat{\mathbb{A}_R}\cong \mathrm{Spf}(R[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]])$ where $R$ is some ring. These are sometimes called 'formal Lie groups' by people like Messing.